# How to do a "generalized" matrix operation in Theano?

Tags: python, matrix, theano

Let's assume that I have a 4-dimensional tensor `A` and I would like to multiply it with a 3-dimensional tensor `B` in the following way:

```
C[i,k,a,b] = sum_{j,l} A[i,j,k,l]*B[a,j,b,l]
```

This is a generalization of matrix multiplication:

```
z[i,k] = sum_j x[i,j]*y[j,k]
```

In other words, I pair some indexes of the first tensor with some indexes of the second tensor and then sum over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right this is done by the `dot` function of `theano.tensor` module.

All the relevant information is in [the doc on linear algebra for tensor with theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#linear-algebra)

You can even go further and specify the axis of summation using `theano.tensor.tensordot`, so to reproduce your example, it could be:

```
import theano.tensor as T

A = T.ftensor4() # create a 4 dimensional float32 tensor
B = T.ftensor4()

C = T.tensordot(A,B, axes=[[1,3],[1,3]]) # here you can specify on which indices to sum

print C.ndim
# >> 4
```